# iOS: How to access textLabel and detailTextLabe of fixed cells?

Tags: ios, tableview, fixed

I have a tableview with fixed cells. I've subclassed the tableview controller and made IBOutlets of all cells. The textlabel is like the title for each cell. The detailTextLabel should be filled with certain database values and later on be changed by the user. However if I try to default the entries, it doesn't work:

```
self.mainCategoryName.detailTextLabel.text = self.category.name;
```

By the way: How do I actually enable user entry into the detail field? Similar to the contacts app on the iphone?

Comment: Fixed cells are static cell in the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

In the Interface Builder set `Style` of static cell to `Subtitle` in `Table View Cell` section of `Attributes Inspector`.